# CodeIgniter Pagination not working: Object not found! Error 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on the pagination for codeigniter. I was able to set it on my page but when I click the next page it will say

> Object not found! Error 404.

My is correctly placed when I click the next, which is *`http://localhost/contents/index/2`*. Also another thing I noticed is that `$config['per_page'] = 2;` yet when I load the page all the data that was looped from a database is shown in 1 page instead of 2 per page.

**Controller**

```
//Pagenation below    
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/contents/index';
            $config['total_rows'] = 200;
            $config['per_page'] = 2; 
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);    
            echo $this->pagination->create_links();

            $data['contents'] = $this->content_model->get_content();
            $data['title'] = 'Contents';
            $this->load->view('template/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
           function index($offset=null){
                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/contents/index/';
                $config['total_rows'] = 200;
                $config['per_page'] = 2; 
                $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);       


                $data['contents'] = $this->content_model->get_content($config['per_page'],$offset);
                $data['title'] = 'Contents';



                $this->load->view('template/header', $data);   
                $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

whole data showing in 1 page because you are not passing limit in model function.you getting 404 because you forgot `/` at the end of the `base_url`

in model

```
function get_content($limit,$offset) {

        $query = $this->db->get('content',$limit,$offset);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

in view

```
 echo $this->pagination->create_links(); //put this in view not in controller
```

Comment: This is what I've got Sir: Missing argument 1 for Contents::index() and Undefined variable: offset

Comment: My data was not displayedT_T, and whenever Iclick no 2 or 3 it shows the "Object not found Error 404",. man I hate that error,.

Comment: did you change route.php

Comment: Yes I changed it, here's my full route.
$route['index/(:num)'] = 'index/$1';
    $route['contents/(:any)'] = 'contents/view/$1';
    $route['contents'] = 'contents';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
    $route['default_controller'] = 'contents';

Comment: for just time comment all routes leave on deafult_controller route after that try my code

Comment: It's still the same, some of my other code didnt showup now so I place it back, I also notice that this code $data['contents'] = $this->content_model->get_content($config['per_page'],$offset); stops my data from being shown. so all I see is my header and the page number. When I use all your code except that one and use my original "    $data['contents'] = $this->content_model->get_content();" it does show the contents but the pagenation is still not working.

Comment: comment only $route['index/(:num)'] = 'index/$1'; and add my updated code in your model

Comment: It's still not working thank you for the help but I think I'll look on  another direction on fixingthis problem, also you forgot to echo the create_links(),.

Answer (score 0):

use have to write the routes to get the values of the page number . You have to add this line to your routes.php in application/config folder

CODE: Routes.php

```
 $route['index/(:num)'] = 'index/$1';
```

index function in index.php :

```
function index($current_page){ 

$this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/contents/index';
            $config['total_rows'] = 200;
            $config['per_page'] = 2; 
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);  
            $this->pagination->cur_page = $current_page;  
            echo $this->pagination->create_links();

            $data['contents'] = $this->content_model->get_content();
            $data['title'] = 'Contents';
            $this->load->view('template/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');

}
```

Comment: I tried and give me an error so I add a value to the ($current_page = 1) and the result was the same, all are in one and when I click the 2 or 3 it will give me the same local host link on my post with the error "object not found error 404.